# Is it possible to run a script on telnet via Playwright C#

Tags: selenium, telnet, playwright

Im trying to make a couple of tests that, if I wish to run completely from beginning to the end, need to do somethings in telnet.

Since Im a complete beginner at this I have no idea where to look and what to try out.

It appears to be possible in Selenium, but we switched to playwright. And to co-workers that made the test are no longer working here. So no idea how they did it.

I dont know where to start. Havent found anything usefull through google yet.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: How did the selenium tests communicate with Telnet?  It would not have been done using the webdriver so I would assume the use of some 3rd party package to achieve that, maybe an npm package.  If you can identify that, perhaps you could do something similar in your playwright project.

Comment: Start by learning how to run the C# playwright test on terminal https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/running-tests . May be you want to say 'run script in terminal'

Comment: As it turnsout they have made theyre own program to do so. It had nothing to do with Selenium, but a program they've made themselfs and runs during the tests aswell.

Thank you all for helping